# Vector-Lua：How to transform table to json ？

Tags: json, lua

ERROR transform{component_kind="transform" component_id=cut_field component_type=lua component_name=cut_field}: vector::internal_events::lua: Error in lua script; discarding event. error=RuntimeErrorHooksProcess { source: RuntimeError("[string "src/transforms/lua/v2/mod.rs:158:17"]:23: attempt to index a nil value (global 'json')\nstack traceback:\n\t[string "src/transforms/lua/v2/mod.rs:158:17"]:23: in function 'hook_process'") } internal_log_rate_secs=30

This is my config:

```
`[transforms.cut_field]
type = "lua"
inputs = ["log_source"]
version = "2"
search_dirs = [ "/usr/lib64/lua" ]
source = """

function hook_process(event, emit)
    if next(event) == nil then
        print("event empty")
    end

    if event == nil then
        print("event is nil")
    end    
    local str = json.encode(event)
    print(str)
    emit(event)
end
"""
hooks.process = "hook_process"`
```

My vector version is: vector 0.17.0 (x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu 3d34cde 2021-10-08)

Comment: json is not part of vanilla Lua, if your environment does not provide a json module you need to load one yourself using `require` if your environemnt provides that function. See https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#pdf-require

Comment: Download [this file](https://github.com/Egor-Skriptunoff/json4lua/blob/master/json.lua), remove the last line #741 `return json` and insert lines #1-740 at the beginning of your Lua code